# Exception in web login form processing in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am trying to create a login page for a cafe shop admin stage.  I know how to link to the main form when logging in successfully, but got an exception trying to process the request.

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string UserName, Password;
    UserName = txtUserName.Text;
    Password = txtPassword.Text;
    LoginByUsingRunTimeObject(UserName, Password);        
}

private void LoginByUsingRunTimeObject(string UserName, string Password)
{
    string connstr = Project304_1.Properties.Settings.Default._20121600ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * t304_users From where userName = @UserName and password = @Password");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UserName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);
    SqlDataReader rdr;
    conn.Open();
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Users");
    dt.Load(rdr);
    if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        frmMain main = new frmMain();
        if (dt.Rows[0][8].ToString() == "admin")
        {

        }

        else if (dt.Rows[0][8].ToString() == "staff")
        {

        }
        main.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
    else
    {

    }
    conn.Close();
    conn.Dispose();
    cmd.Dispose();
}
```

But when I run that, I get the following error:

> **InvalidOperationException**
>
> ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized.

[image]

Comment: `But some problem happened`. We can't guess what that problem is - can you please elaborate and perhaps show us some error messages and stack traces?

Comment: Check out the built-in membership and role providers, assuming you're using ASP .NET

Comment: how to add a picture here?

Comment: @user3487875 you need a certain reputation to do that. Just add a link and one of us who can will make it an image for you.

Comment: "Don't store a password directly in a database without first using some `salt` and `hashing`. A pretty good way to store passwords is to store two values: the `Salt` and then salt your password then hash it and store that hashed password. Then when a user tries to log in you will retrieve the salt and the password they used hash it and see if it is the same as your hashed password value." -- @Khaltazar (who doesn't yet have enough rep to comment)

Comment: how to create a link for image, i used snipping tool and store in my computer

Comment: @user3487875 just post it on imgur or something, anywhere that will give you a publicly accessible link to the image. You could also just tell us the error, particularly in the short-term. Making us look at images of text that we have to zoom in on isn't a great way to get help.

Comment: By the way, `SqlDataReader` is also disposable. You should be sure to dispose of that as well as your other objects to make sure you don't run into issues down the way. I'd suggest implementing `using` blocks, but you could also just call dispose as you do (as long as no unhandled exceptions occur).

Comment: And while we're at it, I see you're getting column values based on numeric indexes and using `SELECT *`. Be careful doing that, since if your table schema changes or columns get unordered, you'll be left with errors. You'd be better to explicitly list the columns you need, or reference them via the string indexer by name.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hyGko.png

Comment: @MatthewHaugen has the right answer but I think once you're past that your SQL is also wrong - `Select * t304_users From` should be `Select * From t304_users` I think.

Comment: oh, yes, petelids is correct!!!  And thank you Matthew Haugen for upload the picture, thanks all!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't setting the `SqlCommand`'s connection. Change your constructor to [include the connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/877h0y3a(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM t304_users WHERE userName = @UserName AND password = @Password", conn);
```

The way you had it, there was no association between the `SqlCommand` and the `SqlConnection`.

I also fixed your syntax as suggested in a comment by user @petelids.

There are enough little things here that I'll just repost your code as I'd write it:

```
string connstr = Project304_1.Properties.Settings.Default._20121600ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM t304_users WHERE userName = @UserName AND password = @Password", conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UserName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);

        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Users");
            dt.Load(rdr);
            if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                frmMain main = new frmMain();
                if (dt.Rows[0][8].ToString() == "admin") // fix this to use a string indexer and not numeric
                {
                    // handle this
                }
                else if (dt.Rows[0][8].ToString() == "staff") // fix this to use a string indexer and not numeric
                {
                    // handle this
                }

                main.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                // handle this
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: oh, yeas, i added just now, but same problem as picture shows.

Comment: Call `SqlConnection.Open()` before you create the command, too.

Comment: @user3487875 I cleaned up your code for you and edited my answer. Although looking at it now that I can read it, you might want to be careful with your `Form.Show()`/`Form.Hide()` pattern. It's fine, but you could wind up in a sticky situation if you get an increasing number of memory-consuming, hidden forms on the screen. You might want to invest a moment to move that pattern to the upper step, whomever shows `this`.

Comment: Hey, Matthew Haugen, how can I view the profile about the account that I login with? Do I need to create a new question?

Comment: @user3487875 I have absolutely no idea what you mean, but probably. I'll see if I can help you when you do. Be sure to include what you've already tried and exactly what error occurred, assuming one did.